# Python / Pandas: Split Dollar Values in a Single Column to Separate Columns

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, iteration

I am new to Python/Pandas, and I think the problem I'm trying to solve is very simple, but I cannot seem to wrap my head around a solution.

I have loaded a CSV file, removed columns I don't need, and sorted the data. Now I'm looking to create a new table based whether or not the "Value" of the quote falls in a certain range. I have successfully sorted some values here:

```
# Sums values between $0 and $10k
Q_Summ10 = Q_Summ_W[(Q_Summ_W['Value'] > 0.0) & (Q_Summ_W['Value'] <= 10000.0)]
print(Q_Summ10)
print(Q_Summ10['Value'].sum())

# Sum values between $10k and $20k
Q_Summ20 = Q_Summ_W[(Q_Summ_W['Value'] > 10000.0) & (Q_Summ_W['Value'] <= 20000.0)]
print(Q_Summ20)
print(Q_Summ20['Value'].sum())
```

I'd like to do this iteratively in $10k increments, and create a new column/index for each increment. The following code is what I've tried and failed with:

```
for i in Q_Summ_W['Value'](10000.0,5000000.0,10000.0):
         sep = pd.DataFrame[('Summ{}'.format(i)):[Q_Summ_W[Q_Summ_W['Value'] > (i - i) & 
               Q_Summ_W['Value'] <= i]]
```

Research tells me I should be using a dictionary or sequence for this, but I'm not sure how to create these with a loop. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do this using `pd.cut` to divide your dataframe in intervals and then `df.groupby` to group your values by interval. Then simply use the `sum()` method over the groupby object to sum all values in each interval.

You didn't provide any example, so the code below acts on a Dataframe with a `Value` column containing random values from 0 to 1, which I then group on 0.1 intervals:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)  # for reproductibility
df = df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': np.random.random(size=100)})
print(df)
# output:
#
#            Value
# 0   0.374540
# 1   0.950714
# 2   0.731994
# 3   0.598658
# 4   0.156019
# ..       ...
# 95  0.493796
# 96  0.522733
# 97  0.427541
# 98  0.025419
# 99  0.107891
#
# [100 rows x 1 columns]

grouped_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Value'], np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))).sum()
print(grouped_df)
# output:
#
#                Value
# Value               
# (0.0, 0.1]  0.699045
# (0.1, 0.2]  2.372805
# (0.2, 0.3]  1.606776
# (0.3, 0.4]  4.057759
# (0.4, 0.5]  3.216896
# (0.5, 0.6]  5.521448
# (0.6, 0.7]  4.428124
# (0.7, 0.8]  8.954358
# (0.8, 0.9]  7.598556
```

Note that `np.arange(0, 1, 0.1))` is simply a convenient way to define an array of fixes-size intervals, that we then use to cut our dataframe by. in my example, it is the array:

```
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
```

You simply need to modify this part the range of values that you want to use as intervals e.g. `(10000.0,5000000.0,10000.0)`.

Comment: Thank you for the help @jfaccioni. I think we're almost there, This works when I include the sum() portion of it, but how do I get it to print all the values that fall in each range? How do I access that data?

Comment: That's a different question that boils down to understanding how `groupby` objects work. In short: if you define `grouped_df` without the `sum()` part (`grouped_df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Value'], np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)))`), you get a `groupby` object. Then you can use `list(grouped_df.indices)` to get a list of the indices (groups) of this object, and pass any of those indices as an argument to `grouped_df.get_group()` to get the values of a specific group. So in my example, `grouped_df.get_group(list(grouped_df.indices)[0])` would return all values inside my first interval `(0.0, 0.1]`.

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help!